# XML not getting generated properly due to special character

Tags: xml, xslt

Now I have an XML which is basically the name of all site and subsites. The XML formation is something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <Sites xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.fakeurl.com">
        <site SId="00600095e-8450-0002-0000-847002f99he" WebId="xyz767-8450-0002-0000-847002f99heb" 
         Url="http://a122.xyz.com" Own="" RecOwn="" Nm="ABC" Desc="ABC" Org="" Pr="" SC="" St="Blank Site" 
         Sr="" CDb="XXCO_PP_ABC_Content_01" ACId="" />
    </Sites>
```

Now one of the site's title has character "VT". I am not able to paste it as it is not taking the symbol(see screen shot below). It says VT when copied in notepad++ and a symbol as arrow with a circle on notepad. On browser if i try to copy it gives an empty space. I will attach the screen shot of the symbol as how it appears in notepad.

Problem is the XML breaks because of this character. I have handeled all the special character possible with proper encoding but this symbol I am unable to replace in my code as I am unable to copy and paste in Visual studio. It only appears in Notepad and notepad ++. Any idea on how to handle this charchter??[image]

Comment: Try replacing encoding attribute value to `utf-8` like this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`.

Comment: That does not help...initially it was utf-8, I changed to ISO to handle other characters

Comment: If your input contains the Vertical Tab character, then it's not XML (at least not XML 1.0) and cannot be processed by XSLT. Use another tool to replace it (or at least change the XML declaration to `version="1.1") before processing the document.

Comment: if i change to 1.1 the browser says the xml version is not supported in chrome

Answer (score 1):

If it's a vertical tab (x0B) then it's not a legal character in XML 1.0. You're going to have to make a decision whether to try and represent it some way, or whether to drop it or substitute it. One way to represent such characters is as processing instructions `<?x 0B?>` but that only works in text nodes, not in attributes.

Switching to utf-8 isn't going to help with this particular character but it's probably a good idea generally if you have no control over the character repertoire in the input.

Comment: Even if I try to substitute it, How can I do it. The XML is getting generated dynamically, if I try to replace a character I should put it my method, here I am unable to copy this character in my visual studio window. It only gets copied in notepad and notepad ++

Comment: If something that purports to generate XML is generating incorrect XML then you manage it like any other program with a bug (or any other faulty product): you get it fixed, or you switch to a different supplier, or you work around it by modifying the inputs or outputs of the faulty program.

Answer (score 0):

Without having the actual code it looks like it might be the vertical tab regex? http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions

to find the character use the HEX ASCII Notepad ++ Convert plugin

hex value of VT is 0x0b
and decimal value is 11

once you know the character use the XSLT replace function.

[How should the '\t' character be handled within XML attribute values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260524/how-should-the-t-character-be-handled-within-xml-attribute-values)

Comment: Michael is suggesting to enter a support ticket with company generating the xml.  You can solve this with Michael's answer to the 'How should the '\t' ... link and substitute the \t used in Michael's correct answer with a \v for vertical tab.