# String manipulation

Tags: c#, java, string, substring, indexof

Alright, say I have the following string:

> 75 \r\n
>                       95 64 \r\n
>                       17 47 82

note that the numbers are seperated by space.

I want my array to have the following elements: 75 95 64 17 47 82.

I've been trying solving it for long but no luck yet..

Can anyone provide any solution or an idea for that?

It's not homework.. I'm just trying to increase my knowledge on string manipulation exercieses.

**EDIT:** Please no LINQ solution since I don't have any knowledge on that subject.

Comment: Do you see the characters "\r\n" in your string, or are you attempting to remove actual carriage return and new-line characters from the string?

Comment: I couldn't help myself. `var intArray = Regex.Matches(s, @"\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value)).ToArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#:

```
string toSplit = "75 \r\n 95 64 \r\n 17 47 82";

string[] numbers = toSplit.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine, "\t", " " },
                                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

The first parameter to Split() is an array of strings that determines what strings to look for in the input string to split around. The second parameter will make sure that any blank entries are removed from the split array.

The array still contains strings, but you can easily convert to your chosen number format afterwards (`short`, `int`, `ushort`, `uint` etc ).

Comment: Looks excellent to me, thanks for the explanation also. It makes much sense for me now.

Comment: BTW, what is the \t used for?

Comment: \t is a tab symbol. The new line (\r\n) can/will vary across different platforms, but tab will always be \t. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294939/environment-constants). If there are any other whitespace chars or escape chars, then they can be added to the string array in the first Split() parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In Java:

```
String yourString = "75 \r\n 95 64 \r\n 17 47 82";
String[] array = yourString.split("\\s+");
```

will remove all whitespace characters: `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use 'replace' to remove the '\r\n' with blank. Looks at the example below :

```
   string s = "75 \r\n 95 64 \r\n 17 47 82";
   s = s.Replace("\r\n ", "");
```

and if you want to put it in array, you can use split

```
   string[] string_arr = s.Split(' ');
```